# Optimizing Element Lookup in Sparse Array on small MCU

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, search

I'm working on an application that involves managing N instances of Element distributed within an array of size M, where N << M (N is much smaller than M). These elements are accessible via their indices, and their distribution within the array is known at build time but follows no specific pattern.

**Primary Goal**: I seek an algorithm that allows efficient (time-wise) retrieval of an element by its index, while also being mindful of space constraints. Ideally, I want to avoid allocating O(M) space, which, although leading to O(1) time complexity, is not feasible for my application.

**Context**: This task is part of developing a CanOpen slave stack for a 16-bit Microcontroller Unit (MCU) operating at 50 MHz and without a Floating-Point Unit (FPU). Traditional hash tables, which might seem like an obvious solution, are not suitable due to the MCU's limitations.

**Current Approach**: I am considering an open addressing hash table utilizing a simplified Murmur hash function. Here's the preliminary function:

```
const int A = 16;
const int B = 0x45d9f3b;
const int C = B;

unsigned int hash(unsigned int x) {
    x = ((x >> A) ^ x) * B;
    x = ((x >> A) ^ x) * C;
    x = (x >> A) ^ x;
    return x;
}
```

I plan to experiment with different values of A, B, and C to minimize access time and reduce collisions. Eventually using an automated script ran a build time to find the best A, B, C constants.

**Question**: Is this approach viable given the constraints, or is there a more efficient algorithm or method better suited for such a scenario? I'm open to alternative suggestions, including the possibility of using a binary search.

### Additional Information

This setup is part of a CANopen slave stack on a small MCU running a real-time application. While CanOpen uses a 16-bit object dictionary, my application requires only 100-200 objects. The key is to minimize access time for each object.

I have limited processing power and no FPU on the MCU. Space efficiency is as crucial as time efficiency.

Comment: Have you evaluated whether or not binary search works for your usecase?
Because if it does, I would go with that. It is more memory efficient (zero overhead in fact) and substantially easier to implement
than any collision free hashing scheme with worst case space requirements of `O(n)`.

Comment: @ChrisB Binary search for 100-1000 entries would be 8-10 comparisons, so 4-5 pipeline flush which would be 30-50 cycles to find the value.

Comment: @nowox How many cycles does it take to compute that hash function? And then the elephant in the room: how many cycles on average does it take to resolve the open addressing?

Comment: @nowox: Without knowning your constraints I will interpret that as 'it would work, but seems very expensive'. My advice would be: go with it, if it becomes a problem, look into perfect hashing.

Comment: @user3386109 This is a good question that I need to figure out. I would say 10-13 cycles max.

Comment: If you need a **perfect hash**, you can kookup **gperf** and its counterparts online. **gperf** is not C++, but does what you seek.

Comment: `gperf` is good for strings, not numbers.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this approach viable given the constraints, or is there a more efficient algorithm or method better suited for such a scenario?

The approach you describe is viable for finding a hash function with a good **average** lookup time.

But I would strongly suggest doing some simple napkin math regarding the probability of collision (you can assume the hash function to be perfectly distributing for simplicity) using the actual memory sizes that you have (but didn't specify in the question) to get an idea about the **worst case**.

You mentioned that you have real-time constraints, so I have a feeling that the worst case time (derived from the maximum length of a collision chain) might not be satisfactory to you. You can have your build time script loop until it finds a solution, but (depending on your constraints) there might not always be one, so your build might fail in rare cases.

An alternative approach would be to use a [perfect hashing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function), which can give you a **guaranteed worst case**, because it has **no** collisions.

Comment: You have not addressed the key question, which is about how much space is needed to make this work. And the answer is that it will be `O(m)`.

Comment: @billy: The perfect hashing approach I suggested can work in `O(n)`. [Here's a fairly easy to read proof of that (under 
10.5.2)](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect1004.pdf). 

I have not done any analysis regarding the collision resistance of the family of Murmur hash functions described in the question. If you have (leading you to the claim of a guaranteed solution in `O(m)` using this hash function), please show your work.

Comment: Since the elements are known at compile-time, space complexity of a pefect hash will be O(N) and the runtime complexity shall be O(log M).

Answer (score 1):

Without further information about the structure of the array, this is impossible.

If you have `100` objects, there are `100^m` possible arrays to encode. There is no way to encode all possible arrays without being able to send that many signals. And that requires `m * log_2(100)` bits. Which is `O(m)` data.

With additional data about the array, it might be possible to reduce the number of possible arrays to encode, and therefore the data storage. But trying to hide the complexity behind hash functions won't save you from the pigeon hole principle - you can't distinguish between `x` different arrays without using enough data to create `x` different possible signals. Which requires a minimum of `log_2(x)` bits.

If you can afford an array of `m` bytes, I would do that. Otherwise you're going to either discover something useful about how the array is generated, or you're going to have to change your goals to something that is doable.